# How to move up and down the layers panel in Photoshop using the keyboard on Scandinavian or German layout?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

On a U.S. keyboard, you use the <kbd>Option</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> keys to move up and down layers.

My problems is that the brackets on the Scandinavian keyboard are located on the 8 and 9 number keys and do not work with the same short cuts.

Comment: Check your keyboard shortcuts under `Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts`

Comment: @Johannes you can't edit those shortcuts, they aren't in the 'Keyboard Shortcuts' list for some bizarre reason.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I've been digging through my shortcuts list, to find them, with no luck too.  I actually just posted on the Adobe forum about this, because I'm curious as well.  I'll post any relevant information I get over there here, to help.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. It's the same for resizing the brush using the square brackets only, doesn't work. There's another decent shortcut for that, alt + right click & drag on windows but it would be useful to traverse the layers with a shortcut.

Comment: Any word on the forums John? Share the link to the post if you can.

Comment: What I ended up doing about the resize brush square bracket key shortcuts was to use "ä" & " ' ", which on my layout are situated where the square brackets are on a US layout.

Answer (score 3):

A friend helped me find the solution!!

Here's my trick:
First change to US keyboard. (win+space if you're on W8 or W10)

In Photoshop, use the Actions Panel! To keep it tidy, create a new group so you don't mix it with default actions. Create a new action and map it to f.ex. 'F2' in the create new actions dialogue.
Record, and Enter 'Alt+LeftBracket' with US Keyboard active. Photoshop will save the command 'Select previous layer'. Create a new recording, map f.ex. 'F3', type 'Alt+RightBracket' and PS will record 'Select forward layer'. Now feel free to change your Keyboard back to your conspicious, outlandish, non-american layout.

F2 and F3 will give you layer select up and down!

Happy days!!

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Some keyboard shortcuts in Photoshop are hard-coded and can't be changed through the normal *Edit → Keyboard Shortcuts...* way (including the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>/<kbd>]</kbd> shortcuts).

Depending on your OS, there are a few workarounds. Basically you either change your keyboard layout, or remap the shortcuts. Any OS should have methods for relatively easily changing keyboard layouts. In OS X you can open keyboard preferences, add a new keyboard input and check 'Show Input menu in menu bar' so you can easily switch between layouts.

- [AutoKeyboard](https://itunes.apple.com/il/app/autokeyboard/id908553210?mt=12) (not free) is an app that allows you to automatically set default keyboard languages for specific apps.
- You should also be able to use something like [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) (also not free) to map new shortcuts, without having to change the keyboard language.
- Some more options to automatically open specific apps with a different keyboard: [SuperUser - Application-specific default keyboard layout in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/157229/application-specific-default-keyboard-layout-in-mac-os-x)
- Related question on Adobe forums: [PS, OS X and Norwegian Apple keyboard, shortcut problems](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/368863)

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution, in case someone is still looking for a method.

You can use:

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd> and <kbd>8</kbd>/<kbd>9</kbd>